# How can ffmpeg extract pictures from several selected time points and scale them?

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I have a mp4 video file and want to extract several images from it, and scale down each extracted image. I took the advice of a similar post to extract the images using select, but when I add scaling, the selection process does nothing and every frame is extracted.

I have tried both of these commands, which differ only in the location of the scaling in the command:

```
ffmpeg -i "$input" -filter:v "select='lt(prev_pts*TB\,1.0)*gte(pts*TB\,1.0) +lt(prev_pts*TB\,6.0)*gte(pts*TB\,6.0) +lt(prev_pts*TB\,11.0)*gte(pts*TB\,11.0)'" -vf scale=480:-1 -vsync drop "/var/tmp/image_i_%d.jpg"
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i "$input" -filter:v "select='lt(prev_pts*TB\,1.0)*gte(pts*TB\,1.0) +lt(prev_pts*TB\,6.0)*gte(pts*TB\,6.0) +lt(prev_pts*TB\,11.0)*gte(pts*TB\,11.0)'" -vsync drop vf scale=480:-1 "/var/tmp/image_i_%d.jpg"
```

with the same problem, the select does nothing.

This command, without the scaling, extracts the desired images, but I need them scaled:

```
ffmpeg -i "$input" -filter:v "select='lt(prev_pts*TB\,1.0)*gte(pts*TB\,1.0) +lt(prev_pts*TB\,6.0)*gte(pts*TB\,6.0) +lt(prev_pts*TB\,11.0)*gte(pts*TB\,11.0)'" -vsync drop "/var/tmp/image_i_%d.jpg"
```

I'm using the latest ffmpeg on Buster, but I tried it with a much older version and have the same problem. My frame rate is not an integer so I'm using the combination of lt and gte, but that's not the issue. The issue is that the use of scaling kills the selection process. The scaling is performed as desired.

Before using 'select,' I used a series of three commands, each with a different seek_time, but that was inefficient and took too long since I have hundreds of these operations to do.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple filters acting on a stream should be applied in the same filterchain, separated by a comma.

So,

`ffmpeg -i "$input" -filter:v "select='lt(prev_pts*TB\,1.0)*gte(pts*TB\,1.0) +lt(prev_pts*TB\,6.0)*gte(pts*TB\,6.0) +lt(prev_pts*TB\,11.0)*gte(pts*TB\,11.0)',scale=480:-1" -vsync drop "/var/tmp/image_i_%d.jpg"`

Comment: Thank you, that runs but there are three issues: (1) I get the error message: "Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up." What are pts, what is the effect, and how do I fix it ? (2) The speed does not seem any better than using three commands with successive seek_times. I thought opening the file once and extracting three images from it would be a lot faster. (3) The scene, which is outdoors, does not change much. For each set of three images extracted, the first is about 15 KB but the other two are about 30 KB. I've looked at them, and they're all about the same. Why so different ?

Comment: Ignore the pts message. select filter will evaluate all frames, so entire file will be decoded. Use input `-ss`. For better quality and bitrate control, add `-q:v` e.g. `-q:v 5`

Comment: Does the select filter evaluate the whole file, which is 15 seconds long and 10 fps, for each timestamp it looks for ? The #1 problem is the time required to get the snapshots. On the same machine, I can use either avconv or ffmpeg. I know there are issues with avconv, but with avconv and seek_time, three per file, it takes just 20 minutes to get a total of 720 snapshots from 240 files. But with ffmpeg and the same file, it takes 50 minutes with select ! This is much too long. I started using select because I thought it would speed things up. How can ffmpeg be so slow ? How can I speed it up ?